# Linq - where a record contains any items within another collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm doing a search of organisations, the users can filter by age groups.

I want to find all organisations that have at least one of the age groups selected.

The selected age groups are stored in a list of ints:

```
model.selectedAges = List<int> selectedAges
```

I have the following query with linq

```
orglist = orglist
        .Where(o => o.AgeGroupCollection.Any(l=>l.AgeGroupID=model.selectedAges.Any());
```

I cant get the part after .Any to work for me.

I need it to get any records where the `agegroupID` == to any of the ints in the selected ages list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to know if the `selectedAges` contains `Any` of the `AgeGroupID`s in the `o`'s `AgeGroupCollection`? Then try like this:

```
orglist = orglist.Where(o =>
        o.AgeGroupCollection.Any(l => model.selectedAges.Contains(l.AgeGroupID)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test this like this `inThis.Any(i => searchThis.Contains(i));`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{    
    static Random r = new Random(); 

    public static void Main()
    {           
        // Testdata
        var searchThis = Enumerable.Range(1,12).Select(_ => r.Next(1,100)).ToList();            

        var inThis = Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(_ => r.Next(90,100)).ToList(); 

        bool isIn = inThis.Any(i => searchThis.Contains(i));

        inThis.Sort();      // for ease of outputting 
        searchThis.Sort();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",searchThis));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",inThis));
        Console.WriteLine(isIn);
    }
}
```

This is simplified as you haven't provided your classes - but it should get the idea across. Outputs:

```
2,13,18,20,33,43,46,56,62,68,79,80  // searchThis
92,93,94,94,95                      // inThis
False

6,11,18,37,39,49,52,58,67,68,71,82  // searchThis
92,95,95,96,98                      // inThis
False

1,2,25,27,32,39,53,61,63,88,89,95   // searchThis
90,94,95,96,99                      // inThis
True
```